# Vuforia Videoplayback баг с отображением видео

Tags: android, видео, vuforia

В данным момент работаю с Vuforia(https://developer.vuforia.com), примером VideoPlayback(https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps/video-playback-sample-app), дело в том, что пример я разобрал, работает как надо, но возникает иногда такая особенность, с которой я не могу разобраться(перепробовал все способы с оф.форума, ничего не помогает). Иногда при наведении на метку видео показывается не так как надо, развернуто.
Ниже скрин для понимания. За любую помощь буду благодарен.
http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20140327/Y6UWM8Xj.png (скрин видеоролика с  цифрой 2).

Comment: когда коплся с вуфорией тоже самое было.присоединяюсь к вопросу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я заменил 
private float videoQuadTextureCoords[] = { 
               0.0f, 1.0f,
               1.0f, 1.0f,
               1.0f, 0.0f,
               0.0f, 0.0f,
            }; 
эту строку) + добавил левый imageTarget, который никогда не встретится) и оп) все заработало) кривая вуфория)

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не работал с этой библиотекой, но раз уж "за любую помощь" :) 
Я так понимаю, видео перевернуто? У каждого видео-файла, записанного на андроид имеется метка поворота (`MediaRecorder.setOrientationHint()`). И, видимо, она пропадает при воспроизведении.

Comment: спасибо не знал этого, но оно кроме поворота видео еще и отзеркаленно:))